# Performantly skip the first N bytes of a stream

Tags: command-line, pipe, performance, macos

I know to use `tail -c +N`, but it is extremely slow, and pins a CPU core:

```
 leijurvs-MacBook-Pro:Downloads leijurv$ time cat /dev/zero | head -c 100000000 | shasum -a 256
a993f8c574e0fea8c1cdcbcd9408d9e2e107ee6e4d120edcfa11decd53fa0cae  -
cat /dev/zero  0.00s user 0.02s system 4% cpu 0.471 total
head -c 100000000  0.01s user 0.03s system 9% cpu 0.470 total
shasum -a 256  0.45s user 0.02s system 99% cpu 0.469 total
 leijurvs-MacBook-Pro:Downloads leijurv$ time cat /dev/zero | head -c 100000000 | tail -c +2 | shasum -a 256
f4be792b71a024a60d77b3ac4c1c2b88ac51480fa25f88d10865827f8c086506  -
cat /dev/zero  0.01s user 0.03s system 0% cpu 7.241 total
head -c 100000000  0.02s user 0.03s system 0% cpu 7.240 total
tail -c +2  7.20s user 0.03s system 99% cpu 7.247 total
shasum -a 256  0.51s user 0.04s system 7% cpu 7.247 total
 leijurvs-MacBook-Pro:Downloads leijurv$
```

`head` is fine. I grab the first 100 megabytes of zero using `head` and shasum it: it takes 0.47 seconds.

I use `tail -c +2` to skip the first byte, suddenly it takes 7.2 seconds.

`tail` pins a CPU core during this.

How can I **performantly** skip the first N bytes of a stream?

Comment: Is it possible (I've not checked) that `tail` starts from the end and works forward until it's two bytes from the start?

Comment: Use `gtail` from GNU coreutils (installable via [brew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/coreutils))?

Comment: Your `tail` example works fine on my Linux box with GNU coreutils - try GNU coreutils' tail as @Freddy suggested perhaps?

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to skip the first byte of a file before feeding to `shasum`, you can just do (here using `zsh` syntax as that `time` output format suggests that's the shell you're using):

```
time cat /dev/zero | head -c 100000000 |
   (LC_ALL=C read -u0 -k1 && shasum -a 256)
```

Then, that means no extra process, that first byte was just read off the pipe by [`read`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-read) before starting `shasum`.

That `LC_ALL=C read -u0 -k1` is `read`ing `1` character (`k` here is for *key* as `read -k` was originally to read keypresses from a terminal), where characters here are single byte thanks to `LC_ALL=C`, from file descriptor `u`nit number `0` (stdin; here to make it explicit we're reading from a stream an not from a terminal).

With the `bash` shell, the equivalent [`read`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-read) command would be `LC_ALL=C IFS= read -rd '' -n1`.

The equivalent of zsh's `read -k` would normally be `read -N`, but that wouldn't work for input containing NUL bytes which `bash`'s `read` just strips (also `-N`, copied from ksh93 is a relatively recent addition which wouldn't be available in the ancient version of bash found on macos). By setting the `d`elimiter to a NUL byte (here expressed as an empty string), we avoid that. `-n1` is to read one character (again made byte thanks to `LC_ALL=C`) from the first NUL delimited record. That means however that it can't be adapted to a different number of bytes as with `-rd '' -n2`, we'd only be skipping one byte if the first byte was 0.

With other shells, you can replace that `read` command with `dd bs=1 count=1 > /dev/null 2>&1` (change `count`, not `bs` to skip more than one byte). `head -c 1 > /dev/null` would also work with *some* of those `head` implementations that support that non-standard `-c` option, but not all (and in particular, not FreeBSD's, so probably not macos' either) as some will read the input in fixed size chunks even if requested to output fewer bytes. However note that contrary to `read` above, they don't report a failure exit status when they fail to read that one byte, so `shasum` would be run in any case.

When the thing to checksum is a regular file instead of a pipe, you can do the *skipping* more efficiently (assuming more than one byte needs to be skipped) by *seeking* within the file rather than reading and discarding the part to skip with (still `zsh` syntax):

```
zmodload zsh/system
{ sysseek 1234567 && shasum -a 256; } < some-big-file
```

To skip the first 1234567 bytes.

Or with ksh93:

```
shasum -a 256 < some-big-file <#((1234567))
```

With other shells and with *some* implementations of `dd` (I can't tell about macos' one), you can do:

```
{ dd bs=1 skip=1234567 count=0 2> /dev/null; shasum -a 256; } < some-big-file
```

However using `count=0` is not portable. Not all `dd` implementations will do the `lseek()` here when the count is 0. Some will even understand it as `count=infinity`.

Answer (score 2):

Mac OSX `tail` is slow.

`brew install coreutils` then switching to `gtail` solves the problem.

```
 leijurvs-MacBook-Pro:~ leijurv$ time cat /dev/zero | head -c 100000000 | tail -c +2 | shasum -a 256
f4be792b71a024a60d77b3ac4c1c2b88ac51480fa25f88d10865827f8c086506  -
cat /dev/zero  0.01s user 0.03s system 0% cpu 7.153 total
head -c 100000000  0.02s user 0.03s system 0% cpu 7.152 total
tail -c +2  7.07s user 0.03s system 99% cpu 7.159 total
shasum -a 256  0.51s user 0.06s system 7% cpu 7.154 total
 leijurvs-MacBook-Pro:~ leijurv$ time cat /dev/zero | head -c 100000000 | gtail -c +2 | shasum -a 256
f4be792b71a024a60d77b3ac4c1c2b88ac51480fa25f88d10865827f8c086506  -
cat /dev/zero  0.00s user 0.02s system 4% cpu 0.497 total
head -c 100000000  0.02s user 0.08s system 18% cpu 0.496 total
gtail -c +2  0.05s user 0.10s system 30% cpu 0.496 total
shasum -a 256  0.47s user 0.02s system 99% cpu 0.496 total
 leijurvs-MacBook-Pro:~ leijurv$
```